# MyBatis exception from generated file

Tags: java, generator, mybatis

I used MyBatis Generator 1.3.1 to create a Mapper.xml file. When MyBatis parses the Mapper file, it throws a BuilderException:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Unknown element <#comment> in SQL statement.
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLStatementBuilder.parseDynamicTags(XMLStatementBuilder.java:83)
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLStatementBuilder.parseStatementNode(XMLStatementBuilder.java:43)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration.parseStatementNodes(Configuration.java:513)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration.buildStatementsForNamespace(Configuration.java:502)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration.buildStatementsFromId(Configuration.java:467)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration.getMappedStatement(Configuration.java:391)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.setupCommandType(MapperMethod.java:160)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.<init>(MapperMethod.java:48)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:37)
    at $Proxy1.selectByExample(Unknown Source)
```

parseDynamicTags is not recognizing the <#comment> field. The portion of the XML that it is parsing is selectByExample:

```
  <select id="selectByExample" resultMap="BaseResultMap" parameterType="test.model.TblPosStageExample" >
    <!--       WARNING - @mbggenerated  ..  -->
    select
    <if test="distinct" >
      distinct
    </if>
    <include refid="Base_Column_List" />
    from tbl_Pos_Stage
    <if test="_parameter != null" >
      <include refid="Example_Where_Clause" />
    </if>
    <if test="orderByClause != null" >
      order by ${orderByClause}
    </if>
  </select>
```

MyBatis seems to have parsed the first comment and the select statement. It has just parsed a node of type #text, but I am not sure where the #comment comes from.

I have not modified the generated file, and I am puzzled that this has functioned correctly in the past and stopped suddenly.

---

EDIT: Base_column_list

```
  <sql id="Base_Column_List" >
    <!--
      WARNING - @mbggenerated
      This element is automatically generated by MyBatis Generator, do not modify.
      This element was generated on Wed Mar 23 08:04:42 EST 2011.
    -->
    SurrogatePK, businessDate, positionId, busAIdCode, {95 columns deleted for brevity}
    marketValueCcy, settledMarketValueCcy
  </sql>
```

And here is the example_where_clause

```
<sql id="Example_Where_Clause" >
  <!--
    WARNING - @mbggenerated
    This element is automatically generated by MyBatis Generator, do not modify.
    This element was generated on Wed Mar 23 08:04:42 EST 2011.
  -->
  <where >
    <foreach collection="oredCriteria" item="criteria" separator="or" >
    <if test="criteria.valid" >
      <trim prefix="(" suffix=")" prefixOverrides="and" >
      <foreach collection="criteria.criteria" item="criterion" >
        <choose >
        <when test="criterion.noValue" >
          and ${criterion.condition}
        </when>
        <when test="criterion.singleValue" >
          and ${criterion.condition} #{criterion.value}
        </when>
        <when test="criterion.betweenValue" >
          and ${criterion.condition} #{criterion.value} and #{criterion.secondValue}
        </when>
        <when test="criterion.listValue" >
          and ${criterion.condition}
          <foreach collection="criterion.value" item="listItem" open="(" close=")" separator="," >
          #{listItem}
          </foreach>
        </when>
        </choose>
      </foreach>
      </trim>
    </if>
    </foreach>
  </where>
</sql>
```

Comment: Could you provide the xml for the "Base_Column_List" and "Example_Where_Clause" references? The error may be originating from one of them.

Comment: @TheClair, OK, I edited the question and added these.

Comment: I'm sorry, nothing is sticking out to me. :( I'd suggest modifying the query to isolate where it's stumbling, but you've probably already tried that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out what caused this problem. (It had nothing to do with the myBatis generation process.)

The problem occurred when I added a utility package to my Eclipse build path, which included a third party library that had many old packages. I suspect that the offending package is an old org.apache.xerces.parsers.

I found the error by building the Eclipse project from scratch and adding packages and code, one at a time.

The runtime error (Unknown element <#comment> in SQL statement) could be reproduced by adding the Project and eliminated by removing the Project from the Build Path.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem caused by a non-standard XML-parser which I cannot replace.
I've opened an issue on the [MyBatis issue management](http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/issues/detail?id=628) and attached a patch. Hope this will be fixed soon.

Edit: As it turns out the problem have been solved in r5388.